# How to initialize a list with part of an array in Java

Tags: java

In Java, I want to create a list based on part of an array, for example, those starting from position 2 (indexed of course from 0) to position 8, what is the convenient way of doing so without explicitly looping?

Thanks.

Comment: because there are faster and better ways?

Comment: faster? what do you think they run behind the scenes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 2, 8));
```

---

**EDIT:**

To create a variable-size arraylist, use the following:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 2, 8)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.arraycopy`

```
arraycopy(source, 2, destination, 0, 7);
```

will copy 7 elements from `source[2]` through `source[8]` to `destination[0]` through `destination[6]`.